# Minimum and maximum possible value of a shared variable when incremented by multiple threads

Tags: multithreading

I have a global shared variable and that is being updated 5 times by each of the 5 threads spawned. As per my understanding the increment operation is consisting of 3 instructions

```
load  reg, M
inc reg
store reg, M
```

So I want to ask that in this scenario what would be the maximum and minimum value given arbitrary interleaving in the 5 threads.

So according to me the maximum value will be 25 ( I am 100% sure that it can be more than 25) and the minimum value is 5. But I am not so sure on minimum value. Can it be less that 5 in some arbitrary interleaving ?
Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

```
/* Global Variable */
int var = 0;

/* Thread  function */
void thread_func()
{
     for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
             var++;
}
```

Comment: why are you attempting to update a 'global' variable without a lock?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat it makes for a more "interesting" theoretical question?

Answer (score 18):

Given your definition of increment, I agree with your max of 25.

However, I believe the min can be 2 under the following scenario.  I've named the 5 threads A, B, C, D and E.

1. A loads 0
2. C, D, E run to completion
3. B runs through 4 of its 5 iterations.
4. A increments 0 to 1 and stores the result (1).
5. B loads 1
6. A runs to completion
7. B increments 1 to 2 and stores 2.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the same logic given by jtdubs, the minimum value should be 1 in the following case.

Lets use the same naming of 5 threads as A, B, C, D, and E.

1. A loads 0
2. B, C, D, E run to completion and incremented to maximum value 20 (5 increments by each of 4 threads).
3. A increments 0 to 1 and store the result 1.

Comment: What about the other 4 iterations of A?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with a minimum of 2 (not 1).

The minimum equals 1 solution ignores the fact that A still hasn't run to completion after it stores 1 in the shared memory.
With no other thread left to "interfere", thread A must still run through the remaining 4 iterations ending with the result 5.

What the minimum of 2 solution enables is an end-game between the two remaining threads A and B, after all other threads have finished running, leading to the minimum possible outcome.
B "wastes" 4 iterations only to load 1 again, increment it and store 2 after A has run to completion.